# Is having the tailplane at the wings backwash a design flaw?

Tags: wing, control-surfaces

[image]
Most airliners have their tailplane below or above the backwash of the wings, so is placing the tail control surfaces directly in the backwash  of the wing a disadvantage?

Comment: Keep in mind that the wing‘s „backwash“ might manifest only a good deal lower than the wing‘s vertical position along the fuselage, depending on flight conditions - after all, the wing deflects airflow downward.

Comment: It's not a bug, but a feature! Since the downwash angle increases with angle of attack, the elevator sees a lower range of angles than the wing. This means that at wing stall it still operates several degrees below its own stall angle, so being in the downwash makes it more stall-proof. When the wing loses lift (post-stall) and the downwash is reduced, the resulting change in angle of attack pitches the plane down, so again the downwash makes the tail do the right thing.

Comment: Insightful.......this should be an answering not a comment @Peter Kämpf

Answer (score 3):

I would say not really. The main impact would be on what incidence angle to set for the horizontal stabilizer because of the difference in local flow angle in or out of the downwash, and on the trim changes to expect if there are wing flaps, larger trim changes in the downwash, less if out.

For your ultralight, I would say the priority is simplicity and lightness, so just stick the horizontal tail at the most structurally convenient location, which is more or less where it is in the picture, like 90% of the other airplanes out there.

Size it based on the standard formula, make an educated guess (er... calculation) on the incidence angle to set, but make an attachment for the stab leading edge with multiple holes that allows you to change the incidence after flight testing.

And remember that when you test fly your ultralight you are effectively an Experimental Test Pilot taking the risks that go with that job description.

Answer (score 1):

One consideration involves the "T" tail design. During wing stall, the Horizontal stabilizer can be blanked by the wake of the stalling wing, rendering the Horizontal stabilizer almost completely ineffective for stall recovery. This condition is known as Deep-Stall.